# installing PyQt5 in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5

I wrote a program in Python 3.4 and I want to make a GUI for it. I"ve found that PyQt5 - is the tool for it.

1) I've downloaded and installed a binary package of PyQt5 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.4.1/PyQt5-5.4.1-gpl-Py3.4-Qt5.4.1-x32.exe).

2) I tried to run this example code in Python:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Python returned en error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyQt5.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
  File "D:\PyQt5.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'; 'PyQt5' is not a package
```

3) I found an advise to install QT. So, I downloaded and installed QT (http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-opensource-windows-x86-online.exe).

4) Then I've uninstalled and installed again a binary package of PyQt5.
No results.

Python doesn't return any errors if I run:

```
import PyQt5
```

But if I try to run:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
```

It returns the same error as in the beginning.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyQt5.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
  File "D:\PyQt5.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'; 'PyQt5' is not a package
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does your code include `import sys`?

Comment: Yes, it does include "import sys". But it does not change the situation (still gives the same error), so I didn't mention it.

Comment: Pynchia, I edited code in question. thanks, but this doesn't help. the problem is in importing QtWidgets or some other part of PyQt or Qt. And not in the last line of code.

Comment: ok, then it import PyQt5, but it complains it is not a package. Locate it and check it is indeed a package (i.e. its directory contains the file `__init__.py` )

Comment: if I understood you correctly - yes. ther is a directory "c:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\" and ther is a file __init__.py in it. (with underlines)

Comment: but this file (__init__.py) has no code inside: # Copyright (c) 2015 Riverbank Computing Limited <info@riverbankcomputing.com>
# 
# This file is part of PyQt5.
# 
# This file may be used under the terms of the GNU General Public License
# version 3.0 as published by the Free Software Foundation and appearing in
# the file LICENSE included in the packaging of this file.  Please review the
# following information to ensure the GNU General Public License 
......

Comment: yes, it does not need to contain anything. But it makes PyQt5 a package. It's a rather odd behaviour then. If I were you I'd start the installation over from scratch.

Comment: Do not call your program file the same as a package name. You're trying to import your own file `D:\PyQt5.py`

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT!!!!!! )))))))) Thanx!!!! I changed the name of the file and it worked! (how to mark your comment as an answer?)

Comment: well, now you can mark the answer -)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Python documentation states](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), the directory containing the input script precedes all the other search paths unless `sys.path` list is tampered with.

And your directory `D:\` already contains module `PyQt5` which is being imported. Trying to import submodule `QtWidgets` from your module that is not a package then leads to the following error:

> ```
> File "D:\PyQt5.py", line 2, in <module>
>   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
> ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'; 'PyQt5' is not a package
> ```

So, do not call your program file the same as a package name.

Answer (score 0):

For the googlers out there, this is what solved my problem:

You need to make sure you import sys and have the proper casing for the import command.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
```

That is the correct casing of the `PyQt5` string. That took me a while to figure out.